What is the difference between an open set and and open subset in topology?
Is it just that open subsets are subsets of open sets?
I was reading the definition of a product topology when I came across the term and I see no reason why we'd have to consider only a subset and not a set.
Here's the definition: Product topology: Let X and Y be topological spaces. The product topology on XxY is the topology having as basis the collection B of all sets of the form UxV where U is an open subset of X and V is an open subset of Y.

There is no difference.  It's just language.

Wait....It just occured to me that they probably mean a subset of X that also happens to be open in X. Is that right?

Yes.  It's not a big deal.

Alright. Thanks!

If you like, the definition could be restated: ".... is the topology having as basis the collection $B$ of all subsets of $X \times Y$ of the form...". But if it is already clear from the context that the "sets" in question are, more particularly, subsets of $X \times Y$, that's not really necessary.
